# PSQL not counting all entries

Tags: sql, count, where-clause, psql, pgadmin

I am writing a count query which counts attendances at events over a few years. However there is a column named `status` in which it has extra information about attendance. `Apology` is listed when the person did not attend and thus should be excluded. `status` has various entries including group's letters, attendance information, guest status, as well as `NULL` entries.

The problem is that not all of the attendances are counted in full. They are counted in full when the `status NOT LIKE 'Apology'` is removed.

How can I get it to count all of the entries? Rather than a limited selection of 364 out of 1583.

I am using `psql` v9.3.11 in pgAdmin III v1.18.1.

The following is the relevant code:

```
SELECT b.attendances,
    COUNT(b.attendances)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(a.event_id) as attendances
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event_id AS event_id,
        member_pers_id AS member_pers_id
        FROM event_attendance
        WHERE status NOT LIKE 'Apology') a
    GROUP BY member_pers_id
    ORDER BY attendances) b
GROUP BY attendances
ORDER BY attendances ASC
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get it to count all entries. What can I add to make this clearer above?

Comment: No wildcard needed. 'Apology' is the exact text. It is more an issue with not selecting all.

Comment: OK, that also does not work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `NOT LIKE` is filtering out additional values, such as `NULL`.  If so, then test for this explicitly.

Also, it makes no sense to do so many aggregations.  One is sufficient:

```
      SELECT COUNT(a.event_id) as attendances
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event_id, member_pers_id
            FROM event_attendance
            WHERE status NOT LIKE 'Apology' OR status IS NULL
           ) a
```

And I'm not sure if the `SELECT DISTINCT` is necessary

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that. Weird logical anomaly as surely `NULL` should count as not something but the process must stop there.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is necessary as there are multiple entries for attendance per event if they invited multiple guests. Good pickup without context though.